# Understending integrals with respect to a function with values in a measure space

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I would be interesting in understanding the precise definition of the integral 
 $$f(A)=\int_a^b p(t,A) dt \quad A \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$$
with $P$ a suitable function from $\mathbb R$ to the space of measures. 
I find this integral quite often when, for example, dealing with the Chapman Kolmogorov equation.

My question is how is this integral defined?

If we fix $A$ we could define $p_A(t)=p(t,A)$ and hence for every $A$: 
$$f(A)=\int_a^b p_A(t) dt $$
where the integral is the classical Riemann integral.

But, is this equivalent to define f as the measure such that 
$$\| f- \sum_i(\cdot,t_i)(x_{i+1}-x_i ) \|_M \rightarrow 0$$
as $C(P) \rightarrow 0$, where $P$ is a partition of the interval $[a,b]$ in intervals $[x_{i+1},x_i] \ni t_i$ and $C(P)$ its mesh and $\| \cdot \|$ is a norm in the space of measure, for example total variation.

What confuses me is that I never read the definition of such an integral and this confuses me.

Comment: It is not recommended to use Riemann integrals in  connection with transition kernels and Chapman _ Kolmogorov's equation. Instead, you should use the Kolmogorov's model of Probability Theory based on measure theory.

Comment: So how should I interpret it? Should I use the Lebesgue integral?

Comment: Yes, the integral is suppose to be a Lebesgue integral.

Comment: Ok. Maybe this question is not meaningful, but I would like to understand the following. Also with a Lebesgue integral, is the integral f(A) defined, for every A, as the limit of simple functions, e.g a_n(A) 1_{S_k} or is it the measure f such that $\| f- \sum a_n(\cdot ) \mathcal L(S_n)\|_M \rightarrow 0$ ? Or maybe are these the same?

Comment: Once you fix a measurable set $A$, then the mapping $t \mapsto p(t, A)$ is nothing but a measurable function. So you can integrate this function just like for other measurable functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. The resulting integral $f(A)=\int_{[a,b]}p(t,A)\,\mathrm{d}t$ then defines a measure on $\mathbb{R}$.